# cannot install html or re via pipenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipenv

I tried to install the packages html and re via pipenv. But I always get problems with the pipfile locking, this is an example error output for html.

```
$ pipenv install html --verbose
Installing html…
⠋ Installing...Installing 'html'
$ ['/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/padobserver_mini-gIRpZkwy/bin/pip', 'install', '--verbose', '--upgrade', 'html', '-i', 'https://pypi.org/simple']
Adding html to Pipfile's [packages]…
✔ Installation Succeeded 
Pipfile.lock (465a67) out of date, updating to (977576)…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
✘ Locking Failed! 
Using pip: -i https://pypi.org/simple
Using pip: -i https://pypi.org/simple
Using pip: -i https://pypi.org/simple

                          ROUND 1                           
Current constraints:
  datetime
  html

Finding the best candidates:
  found candidate datetime==4.3 (constraint was <any>)
  found candidate html==1.16 (constraint was <any>)

Finding secondary dependencies:
  datetime==4.3             requires pytz, zope.interface
  html==1.16 not in cache, need to check index
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 126, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 119, in main
    parsed.requirements_dir, parsed.packages)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 85, in _main
    requirements_dir=requirements_dir,
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 69, in resolve
    req_dir=requirements_dir
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 726, in resolve_deps
    req_dir=req_dir,
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 480, in actually_resolve_deps
    resolved_tree = resolver.resolve()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 385, in resolve
    results = self.resolver.resolve(max_rounds=environments.PIPENV_MAX_ROUNDS)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", line 102, in resolve
    has_changed, best_matches = self._resolve_one_round()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", line 206, in _resolve_one_round
    for dep in self._iter_dependencies(best_match):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", line 301, in _iter_dependencies
    dependencies = self.repository.get_dependencies(ireq)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 234, in get_dependencies
    legacy_results = self.get_legacy_dependencies(ireq)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 426, in get_legacy_dependencies
    results, ireq = self.resolve_reqs(download_dir, ireq, wheel_cache)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 297, in resolve_reqs
    results = resolver._resolve_one(reqset, ireq)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/resolve.py", line 260, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/resolve.py", line 213, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 294, in prepare_linked_requirement
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist(finder, self.build_isolation)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 127, in prep_for_dist
    self.req.run_egg_info()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 474, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 705, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
pipenv.patched.notpip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/tmpb736w9bfbuild/html/
Using pip: -i https://pypi.org/simple
Using pip: -i https://pypi.org/simple

                          ROUND 1                           
Current constraints:
  datetime
  html

Finding the best candidates:
  found candidate datetime==4.3 (constraint was <any>)
  found candidate html==1.16 (constraint was <any>)

Finding secondary dependencies:
  datetime==4.3             requires pytz, zope.interface
  html==1.16 not in cache, need to check index
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 126, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 119, in main
    parsed.requirements_dir, parsed.packages)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 85, in _main
    requirements_dir=requirements_dir,
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 69, in resolve
    req_dir=requirements_dir
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 726, in resolve_deps
    req_dir=req_dir,
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 480, in actually_resolve_deps
    resolved_tree = resolver.resolve()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 385, in resolve
    results = self.resolver.resolve(max_rounds=environments.PIPENV_MAX_ROUNDS)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", line 102, in resolve
    has_changed, best_matches = self._resolve_one_round()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", line 206, in _resolve_one_round
    for dep in self._iter_dependencies(best_match):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", line 301, in _iter_dependencies
    dependencies = self.repository.get_dependencies(ireq)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 234, in get_dependencies
    legacy_results = self.get_legacy_dependencies(ireq)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 426, in get_legacy_dependencies
    results, ireq = self.resolve_reqs(download_dir, ireq, wheel_cache)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 297, in resolve_reqs
    results = resolver._resolve_one(reqset, ireq)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/resolve.py", line 260, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/resolve.py", line 213, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 294, in prepare_linked_requirement
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist(finder, self.build_isolation)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 127, in prep_for_dist
    self.req.run_egg_info()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 474, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 705, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
pipenv.patched.notpip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/tmpb736w9bfbuild/html/
```

I don't see any hints in this output, to find the problem?! Looks like its trying it two times and seems to fail when checking index for html. But I dont know why it fails here

Comment: The packages `html` and `re` are part Python's standard library. There should be no need to install them explicitly.

Comment: @rincewind ok, but is that the reasons it is not working?

Comment: Making this an answer then...

Answer (score 2):

The packages `html` and `re` are part Python's standard library. There should be no need to install them explicitly and trying to install them will get you *some other* packages from the [cheeseshop](http://pypi.python.org/) named like the standard packages. You almost never want to do that.

In this case `pip` (used by `pipenv`) selects [good'ol Zope](http://www.zope.org/)'s DateTime package  und a package called `html` from the [cheeseshop (The Python Package Index or PyPI)](http://pypi.python.org/). This `html` package is ancient (last release in 2011) and does'nt seem to work with python's more modern packaging systems (it's `setup.py` does not understand the command `egg_info`; Python has a long and dark history of conflicting package management systems)

Python does not prevent you from reusing the names of packages in the standard library. And neither does PyPI. The old `DateTime` package i.e. predates python's builtin `datetime` module IIRC.

The `html` package you are trying to install via `pipenv install html` is not the `html` module from Python's standard library but [this one](https://pypi.org/project/html/).

Comment: Wow! If I understood correctly:  this `html`-module is  module that I saw from time to time preinstalled on ancient versions of Redhat/CentOS. It was pretty common source of confusion for system administrators. I did not saw it in last 2-3 years and supposed it gone forever

Comment: `html`  is still available on PyPI and helps with producing html. I don't know if it was commonly used. The  `html` module with `escape()` and `unescape()` has been added to the python standard library with version 3.2 in 2016.

Comment: Maybe I'm confusing it with another module but typical case was: "Help me with this script" - "OK" - 2 minutes later: "Man, you have incorrect `html`, where did you got it?" - "I don't know the script came with Redhat/CentOS" ... "use this [script with [stdlib `html` or `lxml` or even `BeatyfulSoup`". Although in most cases it was incorrect PYTHONPATH